# how to delete a specific row in the html table and database

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I wrote a table in html which consists of 6 columns with 6th column as a delete button.The rows will gets updated dynamically.

Now my first question is how to delete a row when we click that rows delete button and even in the database also.

Second question is, there are check boxes with every row and a delete1 button on the top on the table. If I checked some rows in table and click the delete1 button then those records must be deleted in the database.

How can this be done.

The below is my jsp code.

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')"/><br>
<table id="dataTable" border="15" >
<tr><th colspan="6" align="center">Data</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b></b></td>   
        <td><b>Institution Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Location</b></td>
        <td><b>Status</b></td>
        <td><b>Edit</b></td>
        <td><b>Delete</b></td>
    </tr>
<%
    Session ses=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx=ses.beginTransaction();
    Query q1=ses.createQuery("from RegisterPojo as rp");
    List<Enumeration> l= q1.list();
    for(int i=0; i<l.size();++i) {
        RegisterPojo rp=(RegisterPojo)l.get(i);
        System.out.println(rp.getInstName());
        System.out.println(rp.getInstName());
%>      
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="<%= rp.getNo()%>"></td>
        <td><%= rp.getInstName()%></td>
        <td><%= rp.getLocation()%></td>
        <td><%= rp.getStatus()%></td>
        <td><a href="register.jsp">Edit</a></td> 
        <td><INPUT type="button" value="Delete"/></td>
        </tr>
<%
    }
%>
</table>
```

NOTE: I saw these type of questions in stackoverflow and even in some other websites but they didn't match my case.

Comment: i think u wud be better off matching their case.. no offence..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: you want to do us your task or asking an specific doubt ??

Comment: i'm not asking the task. just want an idea on how to delete/update a specific row in a html table and database table, i.e how to differentiate one row from another so that i can carry on with my work.That is my intention, may my question(english) make u ask like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the tutorial at the following website:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/

As for adding or deleting content from a database, I imagine you would want table.rows[n].innerHTML or table.rows[n].innerText and use a select and delete query from the database.

If one particular column is used as your key in the database, then you can use table.rows[n].cells[key].innerHTML or table.rows[n].cells[key].innerText to get just that cell's values and then do your queries with that.